# Point estimate and margin of error

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

> The effectiveness of a blood-pressure drug is being investigated. An experimenter finds that, on average, the reduction in systolic blood pressure is 39 for a sample of size 19 and standard deviation 8.
>
> Estimate how much the drug will lower a typical patient's systolic blood pressure (using a 98% confidence level).
>
> Give your answers to one decimal place and provide the point estimate with its margin of error.

I began by finding the upper an lower bounds.
$\Rightarrow 39 \pm \dfrac{8}{\sqrt{19}}$
$= 34.340$ and $43.660$

Then I went on to find the point estimate:
$p=(34.340+43.660)/2=39$
but $p=X/n$
$\Rightarrow  X= 19 \cdot 39=741$.

I put this in and the computer says I'm wrong.

My margin of error is $4.7$ (which is correct).

The standard deviation is the sample SD. And the formula  she gave is of the form $x_{mean} ± t_{\alpha/2}  \cdot s/\sqrt{2}$. Using t-table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Several difficulties here: (1) You do not say whether the 'standard deviation' 8 that you give is the sample SD $S$ or the population SD $\sigma.$ (That would make the difference between a z conf interval and a t conf interval. (2) Your proposed interval $39 \pm 8/\sqrt{19}$ seems to be of the form $\bar X \pm SE$, where SE is the 'standard error of the mean', but it lacks a 'probability factor' and cannot be a confidence interval. (3) Towards the end, you seem to switch to using a 'point estimate' $p$ of a type that is unknown to me. What discussion in the text/notes precedes this question?

Comment: The edit by @TheChaz done while I wrote the previous Comment fixes TeX formatting, but contributes nothing toward clarification of the statistical issues.

Comment: @BruceET Did you get the point estimate of 741 I got? And the prof. said we should use t-tables

Comment: The standard deviation is the sample SD. And the formula  she gave is of the form x(mean)= t(alpha/2)* s/√2. NB:parenthesis stands for subscript

Comment: The equation $p = X/n$ seems to be for a point estimate of a binomial proportion. I cannot see how that makes any sense for your problem. If you mean to ask whether I agree that $19 \times 39 = 741$, then that seems simple enough. If you mean to ask whether this computation has any valid connection with the problem, then I'm very doubtful.

Comment: @BattleDrum The formula is $\overline x-t_{\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2},n-1\right)}\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt n}$ for the lower bound. For what is asked ? What value do you have to input into the computer  now ? This is not clear to me.

Comment: It should be of the form point estimate +/- margin of error

Comment: Then $39\pm 4.7$ should be correct. Or maybe whole numbers are better $39\pm 5$.

Comment: @calculus. I think you are on the right track with $\bar X \pm t^*s/\sqrt{n}$. Go ahead. Have to administer a 2hr midterm exam in a bit. No more time now.

Comment: @calculus Worked. Thanks.

Comment: @BattleDrum What worked ? What value have you input ?

Comment: @calculus 39 ±4.7

Comment: O.K. You´re welcome.

Comment: @calculus. For the point estimate did you just average 34.30 and 43.660, or you used some other formula. Kindly share.

Comment: @BattleDrum The average of the sample is 39. This value is given in the exercise. I hope I understand your question right.

Comment: @calculus I do thanks.